# Map Dataframe Columns Based on Priority

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a main dataframe(main_df) like:

```
     A     B       X    Y     Id1
0  cat  cat1  catabc  0.1  uuid01
1  cat  cat1  catxyz  0.4  uuid02
2  cat  cat2  catpqr  0.5  uuid01
3  dog  dog1  dogxyz  0.3  uuid03
4  dog  dog2  dogpqr  0.2  uuid02
5  dog  dog2  dogabc  0.8  uuid01
```

And another dataframe(map_df) which will help in mapping:

```
     A     B       X    Y   Id2
0  cat  cat1  catxyz  0.4  nx01
1  cat  cat1     NaN  NaN  nx02
2  cat   NaN     NaN  NaN  nx03
3  dog  dog1  dogxyz  NaN  nx04
4  dog   NaN     NaN  NaN  nx05
```

The priority of mapping for columns will be in the order: `['A', 'B', 'X', 'Y']`.

So, if all cells of a row `map_df` match with any row of `main_df`, then the corresponding element of `Id2` should be added to `main_df`. If `Y` is not present, then the mapping should proceed with `['A', 'B', 'X']`; if `X` is also absent, it should proceed with `['A', 'B']` and so on..

I was able to achieve partial result with dataframe merge. For example:

```
main_df = main_df.merge(map_df, how='left', on=['A', 'B', 'X', 'Y']))
```

But I am unable to figure out the priority-based angle here.

As a result of mapping, the dataframe(result_df) should be like:

```
     A     B       X    Y     Id1   Id2
0  cat  cat1  catabc  0.1  uuid01  nx02
1  cat  cat1  catxyz  0.4  uuid02  nx01
2  cat  cat2  catpqr  0.5  uuid01  nx03
3  dog  dog1  dogxyz  0.3  uuid03  nx04
4  dog  dog2  dogpqr  0.2  uuid02  nx05
5  dog  dog2  dogabc  0.8  uuid01  nx05
```

Comment: not too elegant way i to do 4 merges? so you do ['A','B','C','D'] then ['A','B','C'] and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would solve. Not very pretty though.

It is an iterative algorithm that traverses in forward and then in backward direction your data.

The forward pass resolves the merges with progressively lower priority, eliminating the matches from the data structure. It uses an `inner merge` strategy.

The backward pass updates the output from lowest to highest priority.
The final `update` call is a bit slow, I noticed.

```py
merge_on = ['A', 'B', 'X', 'Y']
tot_cols = len(merge_on)

operation_main_df = main_df.copy()
outputs = []

# forward pass on progressively smaller sets
for first_idx in range(len(merge_on)):
    
    merged_id2 = operation_main_df.merge(map_df, how='inner', 
           on=merge_on[0:tot_cols-first_idx],right_index=True,suffixes={"","_y"})                                                             
   
    # the relevant output has the right number of NaN columns, the rest is garbage.
    outputs.append(merged_id2[merged_id2.isna().sum(axis=1)==first_idx])


# backward updating pass
reverse_it = iter(outputs[::-1])

out = next(reverse_it)[['A','B','X','Y','Id1','Id2']].copy()
for el in reverse_it:
    out.update(el)
```

output:

```
A   B   X   Y   Id1 Id2
0   cat cat1    catabc  0.1 uuid01  nx02
1   cat cat1    catxyz  0.4 uuid02  nx01
2   cat cat2    catpqr  0.5 uuid01  nx03
3   dog dog1    dogxyz  0.3 uuid03  nx04
4   dog dog2    dogpqr  0.2 uuid02  nx05
5   dog dog2    dogabc  0.8 uuid01  nx05
```

EDIT: accelerates of a 10x factor on my machine

```py
# change
out = next(reverse_it)[['A','B','X','Y','Id1','Id2']]

# into
out = next(reverse_it)[['A','B','X','Y','Id1','Id2']].copy()
```

Comment: The solution is working. Thank you. But I feel this answer can be improved with help from the answer from Rob Raymond. The iterations are pretty slow for very large dataframes.

Comment: @AsifIqbal, edited in a way that goes 10x faster on my machine. see change

Answer (score 1):

Using concepts of how an SQL engine can work with complex query.  Generate a partial Cartesian product then filter down results to required set.

In this case a calculated match (weight)

```
result_df = (main_df
 # minimum match - just A, effectivaly a partial catersian producr
 .merge(map_df, on=["A"], suffixes=("","_m"))
 # calculate weight of match.  NaN is neutral, different penalise, same reward
 .assign(
     B_w=lambda dfa: np.where(dfa["B_m"].isna(), 0, np.where(dfa["B"]==dfa["B_m"],1,-1)*1000),
     X_w=lambda dfa: np.where(dfa["X_m"].isna(), 0, np.where(dfa["X"]==dfa["X_m"],1,-1)*100),
     Y_w=lambda dfa: np.where(dfa["Y_m"].isna(), 0, np.where(dfa["Y"]==dfa["Y_m"],1,-1)*10),
     w=lambda dfa: dfa.loc[:,["B_w","X_w","Y_w"]].sum(axis=1)
 )
# biggest weight is one we want
 .sort_values(["A","B","X","Y","w"], ascending=[True,True,True,True,False])

 .groupby(["A","B","X","Y"]).first()
#  # cleanup and don't show workings...
 .reset_index()
 .loc[:,["A","B","X","Y","Id1","Id2"]]
)
```

In this case it's the longest available key.

```
main_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""     A     B       X    Y     Id1
0  cat  cat1  catabc  0.1  uuid01
1  cat  cat1  catxyz  0.4  uuid02
2  cat  cat2  catpqr  0.5  uuid01
3  dog  dog1  dogxyz  0.3  uuid03
4  dog  dog2  dogpqr  0.2  uuid02
5  dog  dog2  dogabc  0.8  uuid01"""), sep="\s+")
map_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""     A     B       X    Y   Id2
0  cat  cat1  catxyz  0.4  nx01
1  cat  cat1     NaN  NaN  nx02
2  cat   NaN     NaN  NaN  nx03
3  dog  dog1  dogxyz  NaN  nx04
4  dog   NaN     NaN  NaN  nx05"""), sep="\s+")

# result_df = 
result_df = (main_df
 # minimum match - just A, effectively a partial catersian product
 .merge(map_df, on=["A"], suffixes=("","_m"))
 # simpler to use empty string for NaN
 .fillna("")
 # synthetic column of rest of key and length
 .assign(c=lambda dfa: dfa["B_m"]+dfa["X_m"]+dfa["Y_m"].astype(str),
                l=lambda dfa: dfa["c"].str.len())
 # longest synthetic key is one we want
 .sort_values(["A","B","X","Y","l"], ascending=[True,True,True,True,False])
 .groupby(["A","B","X","Y"]).first()
 # cleanup and don't show workings...
 .reset_index()
 .loc[:,["A","B","X","Y","Id1","Id2"]]
)
```

### output (using weighted method)

```
     A     B       X    Y     Id1   Id2
0  cat  cat1  catabc  0.1  uuid01  nx02
1  cat  cat1  catxyz  0.4  uuid02  nx01
2  cat  cat2  catpqr  0.5  uuid01  nx03
3  dog  dog1  dogxyz  0.3  uuid03  nx04
4  dog  dog2  dogabc  0.8  uuid01  nx05
5  dog  dog2  dogpqr  0.2  uuid02  nx05
```

Comment: I would have loved this solution if the resulting dataframe was as expected. This solution doesn't use an iterative mechanism and will be pretty fast on a large dataframe I can see. But if you look at the resulting dataframe, it doesn't match the expectation.

Comment: @AsifIqbal I'm only working on laptop and not enough screen real estate :-). Updated,  same approach using a better calculation for ranking of match

Comment: btw **w** column shows level of match 1110-4cols, 1100-3cols, etc