# I need to merge a Pandas df (0.22) to ignore NaN in some of the multiple join Keys

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge, nan

So, I have a (long) rule that needs to be applied from an excel/csv import. The rule comes from another system and contains many criteria columns, but these are not always populated. When one or more of the keys is NaN, the desired result is to treat that key as though it were a match.

In this example, I want values for indigo and violet to be -200, not NaN:

```
import pandas as pd,  numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'colour': ['red','blue','green','indigo','violet'], 'jk': ['AAA',"BBB",'CCC','DDD','EEE'], 'jk2': ['q',"q",'q','q','q']})
rule = pd.DataFrame({ 'jk': ['AAA',"BBB",'CCC', np.NaN], 'jk2': ['q',"q",'q','q'], "value": [100,0,10,-200]})

pd.merge(df, rule, how= 'left', on = ["jk","jk2"])
```

I think I could iterate over each row in rule, dropna on columns and join, but it seems a bit clumsy and the rule and data sets are pretty big.

Comment: Do you want to fill all `NaN` values in the `value` column with -200?

Comment: no, not all: only when there is a match on the other key, jk2. In reality there are about 20 criteria columns.

Answer (score 0):

`merge()` twice.  First time to get "full" joins, second to use NaN where "full" didn't give you an answer.  Have left additional columns in place so you can see how it works.  *value_a* contains the values you want.

```
import pandas as pd,  numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'colour': ['red','blue','green','indigo','violet'], 'jk': ['AAA',"BBB",'CCC','DDD','EEE'], 'jk2': ['q',"q",'q','q','q']})
rule = pd.DataFrame({ 'jk': ['AAA',"BBB",'CCC', np.NaN], 'jk2': ['q',"q",'q','q'], "value": [100,0,10,-200]})
(
    pd.merge(df, rule, how= 'left', on = ["jk","jk2"])
    .assign(jk_an=lambda dfa: np.where(dfa["value"].isna(), np.nan, dfa["jk"]))
    .merge(rule, how="left", left_on=["jk_an","jk2"], right_on=["jk","jk2"], suffixes=("","_a"))
)
```

### output

```
 colour   jk jk2  value jk_an jk_a  value_a
    red  AAA   q  100.0   AAA  AAA      100
   blue  BBB   q    0.0   BBB  BBB        0
  green  CCC   q   10.0   CCC  CCC       10
 indigo  DDD   q    NaN   NaN  NaN     -200
 violet  EEE   q    NaN   NaN  NaN     -200
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there are about 30 columns, so I think I'd this doesn't work for the extended rules

Comment: the other approach is a Cartesian product then score matches and take best matches.  [wieghted Cartesian product "join"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65564368/map-dataframe-columns-based-on-priority/65567257#65567257). A more comprehensive data example would help to demonstrate this